# How to change the width of the logo in the Top Suite Bar

Tags: 2016, suitebar

I'm now a administrator of a SharePoint 2016 on-prem site. There is a logo in the Top Suite Bar, but the last 20% is cut. I'm guessing that the maximum width value for a logo is set to be too narrow. I wonder, how do I change that value?

I attach a image to illustrate.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom logo is set to specific dimension as mentioned by Microsoft.

JPG, PNG, or GIF with a resolution of 200 x 30 pixels, no larger than 10 KB. This appears in the top navigation bar on every page.

I suspect may be your image is beyond this resolution so it does not fit.

here is Microsoft refrence Page.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-office-365-theme-for-your-organization-8275da91-7a48-4591-94ab-3123a3f79530

Comment: Aha, so I guess there is now way to make the resolution image limit bigger than 200 pixels?

Comment: You can still try to override css using custom css. custom css can be injected using SPFx extension but its not advisable for top suit bar navigation. it might require a developer hand as you mentioned you are like administrator https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions

Comment: Thank you vinit for you answer! I resized the logo to 200px and it's acceptable.

Comment: Perfect, but now back to default top bar?

Comment: @Fox sorry i did not get you.